# Spring Gateway - Adding of default Request and Response headers

Tags: java, spring, routes, spring-cloud-gateway

There are 2 ways to add request and response headers via a bean from RouteLocator or via properties.
However would need an example to add default filters (below) via a bean as the `service-response-value` and `service-request-value` would be a dynamic value :

```
spring
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - AddRequestHeader= service-request, service-request-value
        - AddResponseHeader= service-response, service-response-value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Cloud Gateway doesn't support default filters via Beans

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/263